# How do I match the data type of my arrays in order to operate and graph my functions in PYTHON and how can I make sure the arrays match length?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, while-loop, geometry

Good day, all!

I was wondering if anyone could assist me in my code for creating the domain and range for my graph plot?

I've been bouncing back and forth between two types of errors:

One can't do the equations because it has to be in a consistent data type. I've tried that but it doesn't work converting it to float. Maybe I have to float everything?

ERROR:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-222a5ee3c353> in <module>
    240     d = np.vectorize(np.arange(.5,1000.5,.5))
    241 
--> 242     a_3 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d
    243     a_4 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d
    244     a_5 = [4*(1/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*((1/2)*d)]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'vectorize'
```

The relevant code is here (purpose to compare and contrast Surface Area to Volume ratio versus diameter and output the information of a constant diameter asked of the user for different types of polyhedra):

CODE:

```
    #Graph Code
    
    if error == '1':
            print("\n")
    else:
        # overwite past input by generated domain for graphing
        d_vertical_slash = d
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np
        # x value generation from picometer to micrometer
        
     
        d = np.vectorize(np.zeros(2000))
        d = np.vectorize(np.arange(.5,1000.5,.5))
        
        a_3 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d
        a_4 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d
        a_5 = [4*(1/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*((1/2)*d)]
        a_6 = [d/math.sqrt(3)]
        a_7 = (2/(math.sqrt(3)*(1+math.sqrt(5)))*d)
        a_8 = ((2/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*d)
        a_9 = ((2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d)
        a_10 = ((3/(math.sqrt(3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))))*d)
        a_11 = ((2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d)
        SA_vex_tetra = (((a_3)**2)*math.sqrt(3))
        V_vex_tetra = ((((a_3)**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2))
        ratio_vex_tetra = [SA_vex_tetra/V_vex_tetra]
        SA_vex_octa = ((a_4)**2)*math.sqrt(3)
        V_vex_octa = (((a_4)**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2)
        ratio_vex_octa = SA_vex_octa/V_vex_octa
        SA_vex_icosa = 5*((a_5)**2)*math.sqrt(3)
        V_vex_icosa = (5/12)*(a_5)**3*(3+math.sqrt(5))
        ratio_vex_icosa = [SA_vex_icosa/V_vex_icosa]
        SA_vex_cube = SA_vex_cube, [6*(a_6)**2]
        V_vex_cube = [(a_6)**3]
        ratio_vex_cube = SA_vex_cube/V_vex_cube
        SA_vex_dodeca = 3*((a_7)**2)*math.sqrt(25+10*math.sqrt(5))
        V_vex_dodeca = (((a_7)**3)/4)*(15+7*math.sqrt(15))
        ratio_vex_dodeca = SA_vex_dodeca/V_vex_dodeca
        SA_cav_gdodeca = [15*((a_8)**2)*(math.sqrt(5-2*math.sqrt(5)))]
        V_cav_gdodeca = (5/4)*((a_6)**3)*(math.sqrt(5)-1)
        ratio_cav_gdodeca = SA_cav_gdodeca/V_cav_gdodeca
        SA_cav_gicosa = 3*((a_9)**2)*math.sqrt(3)*(5+4*math.sqrt(5))
        V_cav_gicosa = (((a_9)**3)/4)*(25+9*math.sqrt(5))
        ratio_cav_gicosa = SA_cav_gicosa/V_cav_gicosa
        SA_cav_gsdodeca = 15*((a_10)**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))
        V_cav_gsdodeca = (5/4)*((a_10)**3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))
        ratio_cav_gsdodeca = SA_cav_gsdodeca/V_cav_gsdodeca
        SA_cav_ssdodeca = 15*((a_11)**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))
        V_cav_ssdodeca = (5/4)*((a_11)**3)*(7+3*math.sqrt(5))      
        ratio_cav_ssdodeca = SA_cav_ssdodeca/V_cav_ssdodeca
            
    
        # convex shapes
        plt.plot(d,ratio_vex_tetra,label='Tetrahedron', color='teal')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_vex_octa,label='Octahedron', color='paleturquoise')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_vex_icosa,label='Icosahedron', color='aqua')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_vex_cube,label='Cube', color='dodgerblue')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_vex_dodeca,label='Dodecahedron', color='paleturquoise')
    
        # concave shapes
        plt.plot(d,ratio_cav_gdodeca,label='Great Dodecahedron', color='green')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_cav_gicosa,label='Great Icosahedron', color='lime')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_cav_gsdodeca,label='Great-Stellated Dodecahedron', color='palegreen')
        plt.plot(d,ratio_cav_ssdodeca,label='Small-Stellated Dodecahedron', color='honeydew')
    
        # sphere reference and chosen reference of diameter
        plt.plot(d,ratio_sphere,label='Referential Sphere', color='r')
        plt.axvline(x=d_vertical_slash, color='b')
    
        # title, labels, grid (for tracing), legend, and output
        plt.title('Comparison of SA:V amongst Concave/Convex Polyhedra as Diameter is held constant across picometer to micrometer range')
        plt.xlabel('Circumspherical Diameter/Diagonal (nm)')
        plt.ylabel('Ratio Index')
    
        plt.grid(alpha=.4,linestyle='--')
    
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
    
        #Concluding message
        print('Thanks for taking the time to look through!')
        print('I hope this shed some light on how important considering')
        print('other styles of 3D geometry is in nanoformulation!')
        print("\n")
        print('Programmed by Wesley Allen Williams')
```

```
The other error happens when I use numpy and I can't find conditions that will terminate the while loop when I want it to:

Aside: I also tried using np.arange to make a floating point array but it did not work...

ERROR:

Something along the lines of not being able to graph because the array is always mismatched in length or shape.... I always remembered it being something like (2001,) and (1, 2001000)...not sure why but it would always add three zeros to the "y" value... or it was truncated to short with my conditions...I got so many errors I didn't get all of them

Code:
```

```
        import math
            
            d = np.array([.001])
            
            a_3 = np.array([(2/math.sqrt(6))*d[0]])
            a_4 = np.array([(2/math.sqrt(6))*d[0]])
            a_5 = np.array([4*(1/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*((1/2)*d[0])])
            a_6 = np.array([d[0]/math.sqrt(3)])
            a_7 = np.array([2/(math.sqrt(3)*(1+math.sqrt(5)))*d[0]])
            a_8 = np.array([(2/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*d[0]])
            a_9 = np.array([(2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d[0]])
            a_10 = np.array([(3/(math.sqrt(3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))))*d[0]])
            a_11 = np.array([(2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d[0]])
            
            SA_vex_tetra = np.array([((a_3)**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
            V_vex_tetra = np.array([(((a_3)**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2)])
            ratio_vex_tetra = np.array([SA_vex_tetra/V_vex_tetra])
            
            SA_vex_octa = np.array([((a_4)**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
            V_vex_octa = np.array([(((a_4)**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2)])
            ratio_vex_octa = np.array([SA_vex_octa/V_vex_octa])
            
            SA_vex_icosa = np.array([5*((a_5)**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
            V_vex_icosa = np.array([(5/12)*(a_5)**3*(3+math.sqrt(5))])
            ratio_vex_icosa = np.array([SA_vex_icosa/V_vex_icosa])
            
            SA_vex_cube = np.array([6*(a_6)**2])
            V_vex_cube = np.array([(a_6)**3])
            ratio_vex_cube = np.array([SA_vex_cube/V_vex_cube])
            
            SA_vex_dodeca = np.array([3*((a_7)**2)*math.sqrt(25+10*math.sqrt(5))])
            V_vex_dodeca = np.array([(((a_7)**3)/4)*(15+7*math.sqrt(15))])
            ratio_vex_dodeca = np.array([SA_vex_dodeca/V_vex_dodeca])
        
            SA_cav_gdodeca = np.array([15*((a_8)**2)*(math.sqrt(5-2*math.sqrt(5)))])
            V_cav_gdodeca = np.array([(5/4)*((a_8)**3)*(math.sqrt(5)-1)])
            ratio_cav_gdodeca = np.array([SA_cav_gdodeca/V_cav_gdodeca])
        
            SA_cav_gicosa = np.array([3*((a_9)**2)*math.sqrt(3)*(5+4*math.sqrt(5))])
            V_cav_gicosa = np.array([(((a_9)**3)/4)*(25+9*math.sqrt(5))])
            ratio_cav_gicosa = np.array([SA_cav_gicosa/V_cav_gicosa])
        
            SA_cav_gsdodeca = np.array([15*((a_10)**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))])
            V_cav_gsdodeca = np.array([(5/4)*((a_10)**3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))])
            ratio_cav_gsdodeca = np.array([SA_cav_gsdodeca/V_cav_gsdodeca])
        
            SA_cav_ssdodeca = np.array([15*((a_11)**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))])
            V_cav_ssdodeca = np.array([(5/4)*((a_11)**3)*(7+3*math.sqrt(5))])
            ratio_cav_ssdodeca = np.array([SA_cav_ssdodeca/V_cav_ssdodeca])
            
            d_prime = d[0] + .499
            d = np.append(d, d_prime)
            i=1
            while d[i] <= 1000:
                a_3 = np.append(a_3, [(2/math.sqrt(6))*d[i]])
                a_4 = np.append(a_4, [(2/math.sqrt(6))*d[i]])
                a_5 = np.append(a_5, [4*(1/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*((1/2)*d[i])])
                a_6 = np.append(a_6, [d[i]/math.sqrt(3)])
                a_7 = np.append(a_7, [2/(math.sqrt(3)*(1+math.sqrt(5)))*d[i]])
                a_8 = np.append(a_8, [(2/(math.sqrt(10+2*math.sqrt(5))))*d[i]])
                a_9 = np.append(a_9, [(2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d[i]])
                a_10 = np.append(a_10, [(3/(math.sqrt(3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))))*d[i]])
                a_11 = np.append(a_11, [(2/(math.sqrt(50+22*math.sqrt(5))))*d[i]])
                SA_vex_tetra = np.append(SA_vex_tetra, [((a_3[i])**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
                V_vex_tetra = np.append(V_vex_tetra, [(((a_3[i])**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2)])
                ratio_vex_tetra = np.append(ratio_vex_tetra, [SA_vex_tetra/V_vex_tetra])
                SA_vex_octa = np.append(SA_vex_octa, [((a_4[i])**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
                V_vex_octa = np.append(V_vex_octa, [(((a_4[i])**3)/12)*math.sqrt(2)])
                ratio_vex_octa = np.append(ratio_vex_octa, [SA_vex_octa/V_vex_octa])
                SA_vex_icosa = np.append(SA_vex_icosa, [5*((a_5[i])**2)*math.sqrt(3)])
                V_vex_icosa = np.append(V_vex_icosa, [(5/12)*(a_5[i])**3*(3+math.sqrt(5))])
                ratio_vex_icosa = np.append(ratio_vex_icosa, [SA_vex_icosa/V_vex_icosa])
                SA_vex_cube = np.append(SA_vex_cube, [6*(a_6[i])**2])
                V_vex_cube = np.append(V_vex_cube, [(a_6[i])**3])
                ratio_vex_cube = np.append(ratio_vex_cube, [SA_vex_cube/V_vex_cube])
                SA_vex_dodeca = np.append(SA_vex_dodeca, [3*((a_7[i])**2)*math.sqrt(25+10*math.sqrt(5))])
                V_vex_dodeca = np.append(V_vex_dodeca, [(((a_7[i])**3)/4)*(15+7*math.sqrt(15))])
                ratio_vex_dodeca = np.append(ratio_vex_dodeca, [SA_vex_dodeca/V_vex_dodeca])
                SA_cav_gdodeca = np.append(SA_cav_gdodeca, [15*((a_8[i])**2)*(math.sqrt(5-2*math.sqrt(5)))])
                V_cav_gdodeca = np.append(V_cav_gdodeca, [(5/4)*((a_8[i])**3)*(math.sqrt(5)-1)])
                ratio_cav_gdodeca = np.append(ratio_cav_gdodeca, [SA_cav_gdodeca/V_cav_gdodeca])
                SA_cav_gicosa = np.append(SA_cav_gicosa, [3*((a_9[i])**2)*math.sqrt(3)*(5+4*math.sqrt(5))])
                V_cav_gicosa = np.append(V_cav_gicosa, [(((a_9[i])**3)/4)*(25+9*math.sqrt(5))])
                ratio_cav_gicosa = np.append(ratio_cav_gicosa, [SA_cav_gicosa/V_cav_gicosa])
                SA_cav_gsdodeca = np.append(SA_cav_gsdodeca, [15*((a_10[i])**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))])
                V_cav_gsdodeca = np.append(V_cav_gsdodeca, [(5/4)*((a_10[i])**3)*(3+math.sqrt(5))])
                ratio_cav_gsdodeca = np.append(ratio_cav_gsdodeca, [SA_cav_gsdodeca/V_cav_gsdodeca])
                SA_cav_ssdodeca = np.append(SA_cav_ssdodeca, [15*((a_11[i])**2)*math.sqrt(5+2*math.sqrt(5))])
                V_cav_ssdodeca = np.append(V_cav_ssdodeca, [(5/4)*((a_11[i])**3)*(7+3*math.sqrt(5))])            
                ratio_cav_ssdodeca = np.append(ratio_cav_ssdodeca, [SA_cav_ssdodeca/V_cav_ssdodeca])
                d_i_plus_one = d[i] + d_prime
                d = np.append(d, d_i_plus_one)
                i+=1
                if d[i] > 1000 or d.size > 2001:
                    break
```

Conclusion:

I'm hoping to successfully plot these curve to compare the SA:V ratio for different polyhedra based off of convexity and concavity...I guess it was too ambitious for me since I just started coding three days ago...go easy on me! I understand this looks extremely incompetent and apologize if it isn't thorough enough.

Also:

Is it possible to build a loop from (.001 to 1000 with a step of .001)? I don't want the user input to be too limited but the while loops I make end up having too many iterations.

Thanks so much if you can parse through this :/...

Comment: Please, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Regarding the first error, what did you want ```d``` to be?

Comment: d is basically the independent variable (domain) for all of the functions/equations I want to plot. It describes the diameter of the polyhedra from .001 nm to 1000nm. and is used to find the side length, a, which is used to solve for SA and V and used to find the ratio which is an equation itself.

Comment: I apologize if the code isn't replicable or reproducible. I am a novice and not sure how to make it so. I'm pretty lost.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is almost certainly not what you want.  Remove that, and your first example should work.

Comment: The problem with a loop from .001 to 1000 in steps of  .001 is that floating point arithmetic is not exact.  If you add .001 a million times, you'll get a number close to 1000, but not exact.  It's better to do `for i in range(1000000):` / `f = i/1000`

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams I also think that np.vectorize is not what you are looking for. If you do just ```d = np.arange(.5,1000.5,.5)```, and then ```print(d)```, the result of the print is ```[5.000e-01 1.000e+00 1.500e+00 ... 9.990e+02 9.995e+02 1.000e+03]```. Is this what you want ```d``` to be?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Why would that for loop be sufficient? I’m not saying it isn’t an excellent answer but I don’t understand. Is that a way to get past floating point and into an integer? And will that For loop take a short time to run? It’s an awful lot of iterations for my equations!

Comment: @fdireito I tried np.arrange before but it didn’t result in an operable domain for the equations, unfortunately.

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams Which was the first equation to give error, in that case?

Comment: You said you wanted 0.001 to 1000 in steps of 0.001.  That's a million steps.  I can't guess how long it will take to run your equations a million times.  It MAY be that you need to start with larger steps and refine downward as performance permits.

Comment: @fdireito The one you commented. I tried that exact one.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Alright, I’ll start at a smaller step size and see! Thanks, I’ll let you know if it worked or I ran into more issues.

Comment: Hey there @TimRoberts, I tried the loop but it was to no avail. I placed to f=i/1000 under for... but I ran into this error randomly:

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int' and it populated at a random equation...if it was an issue with operation...it should have occured with the first video. --> 255         SA_vex_icosa = 5*((a_5)**2)*math.sqrt(3) @TimRoberts

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams That is surprising. Sorry for insisting, but are you sure you do not have some typo? Could you create a separate file with the following code line by line ```import math``` , ```import numpy as np``` , ```d = np.arange(.5,1000.5,.5)```, ```a_3 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d```, ```print(d)```, ```print(a_3)``` (copy paste from here, line by line). This works for me. Try that and see if you get d and a_3 with the values you want.

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams That should give d: ```[5.000e-01 1.000e+00 1.500e+00 ... 9.990e+02 9.995e+02 1.000e+03]``` and a_3 ```[4.08248290e-01 8.16496581e-01 1.22474487e+00 ... 8.15680084e+02 8.16088333e+02 8.16496581e+02]```

Comment: @fdireito That worked really well! The issue was that Numpy doesn't like the way certain equations are structured with their parantheses and wanted simplification. Next up, I had to run through formula typos and I ultimately used a scatter plot for my million data points since it would NOT plot even with matching array lengths. Then I had to simplify the command for the legend since it was overworking my CPU...THEN I had to truncate the data set to 10,000 point as well as plot the domain as a logarithmic function to visualize the change. My hypothesis held true dude! Thanks!!!

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your help as well! My for loop had issues but I'll resolve my knowledge later after midterms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fdireito Answer and response as follows:

@WesleyAllenWilliams That is surprising. Sorry for insisting, but are you sure you do not have some typo? Could you create a separate file with the following code line by line import math , import numpy as np , d = np.arange(.5,1000.5,.5), a_3 = (2/math.sqrt(6))*d, print(d), print(a_3) (copy paste from here, line by line). This works for me. Try that and see if you get d and a_3 with the values you want. – fdireito 13 hours ago

@WesleyAllenWilliams That should give d: [5.000e-01 1.000e+00 1.500e+00 ... 9.990e+02 9.995e+02 1.000e+03] and a_3 [4.08248290e-01 8.16496581e-01 1.22474487e+00 ... 8.15680084e+02 8.16088333e+02 8.16496581e+02] – fdireito 13 hours ago

@fdireito That worked really well! The issue was that Numpy doesn't like the way certain equations are structured with their parantheses and wanted simplification. Next up, I had to run through formula typos and I ultimately used a scatter plot for my million data points since it would NOT plot even with matching array lengths. Then I had to simplify the command for the legend since it was overworking my CPU...THEN I had to truncate the data set to 10,000 point as well as plot the domain as a logarithmic function to visualize the change. My hypothesis held true dude! Thanks!!! – Wesley Allen Williams 6 mins ago   Delete